# Como fazer o container alcançar o rodapé? (mesmo com pouco conteúdo)

Tags: html, css

Tenho um layout aqui, onde, o background do *container* é preto transparente, e ele vai até o rodapé da página. mas tem outro problema, aonde tá escrito "Sitemap", é um menu que desliza para cima, e esse *container* tem que fica atrás desse pedaço, o *footer* tá usando ´position: relative´.
[image: layout do site onde container vai até o rodapé]

esse é o código do container:

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

no código, ´margin-bottom´ negativo foi o jeito que dei de fazer o *container* ficar atrás do início do *footer*, mas o cliente olhou pelo monitor dele e parece que não alcançou, acho que é por causa da resolução da tela dele...(maldição!)

ps: o bg transparent é outra classe que insere o fundo transparente no container.

edit: meu *footer* fica sempre grudado no fundo da página, ou seja, é um *sticky footer*, então, independente do tamanho do monitor, o * footer* sempre fica no fundo, e isso que deixa mais difícil, porque esse *container* deve ficar sempre grudado nele também.

Comment: Se possivel, adicione o seu HTML na pergunta.

Comment: sério? é que é grande pra caramba!

Comment: @LeandroRuel coloque todo seu HTML e todo seu CSS em um exemplo feito neste site http://jsfiddle.net e depois clique em update e pegue o link que será gerado na sua barra de endereços e poste aqui como "Exemplo no JSFiddle" para que possamos te ajudar corretamente

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa resposta de outro post: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/413211/82200

Answer (score 2):

Nesse caso, **coloque o fundo não no conteiner que tem o texto, mas em um conteiner que estaria no fundo dele**.

Caso o HTML do seu site seja simples e não tenha nada de especial no cabecalho, nesse conteiner basta por `height: 100%`. `height: 100%` é uma das coisas mais difíceis de funcionar em CSS porque tem pega-ratões, mas em alguns casos funciona sim.

Recomendo que leia esse artigo do Maujor sobre [Por que height: 100% não funciona?](http://www.maujor.com/blog/2013/03/08/por-que-height-100-nao-funciona/)

**Resumindo a ideia: para `height: 100%` funcionar, todos os elementos pais devem ter atributo `height` definidos, ou os filhos não tem como fazer qual valor é 100%.**

[Exemplo 1: Div não vai até o final](http://maujor.com/blog/pg_apoio/height100/exemplo1.html)

[Exemplo 2: Div VAI até o final](http://maujor.com/blog/pg_apoio/height100/exemplo2.html)

Para os demais exemplo, veja o artigo completo do Maujor. Ele é bem esclarecedor.

Comment: vou tentar fazer isso, cheguei a pensar nisso, inclusive testei primeiro o height:100% no container mas não deu certo, o background nao alcançou o conteudo, nem chegou perto do rodapé

Answer (score 1):

@LeandroRuel, fiz um exemplo que pode ser visto clicando [**AQUI**](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffersonalison/eeP7c/).

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Quase nada de conteudo</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body, html{
  height: 100%;
}

.container{
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Para que o height: 100% neste caso, o meu elemento pai que no caso é o body tem que estar com o height: 100% também.

Por exemplo, se o body estiver com height de 500px e o container com height: 100%, o height do container vai ser de 500px. Pois ele vale 100% do elemento pai.