# Div com height 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou precisando deixar uma `div` com `height: 100%` de conteúdo e abaixo dela ainda ficar o rodapé, mas, por exemplo, quando não tiver conteúdo para completar toda a tela, o rodapé aparece no final da pagina. Ele tem `100px` e quando o conteúdo completar a pagina, o rodapé fica somente depois do conteúdo, após a rolagem mesmo...

Estou com esse problema pois estou usando o *bootstrap* e a minha navbar fica na vertical no canto do lado direito. Minha tag html tem a mesma cor do navbar para completar a cor até o final pois o menu não completa tudo e o rodapé tem a mesma cor dessa sidebar e da tag html.

A minha `div` de conteúdo possui outra cor, quando a pagina não completa tudo, o rodapé sobe e a cor do rodapé fica estendida até boa parte da página, deixando esteticamente feio. O rodapé devia ficar no fim da pagina e a cor da parte de conteúdo ficasse ate onde aparece o rodapé.

Alguém tem alguma solução pra isso?

Comment: Pode postar o código no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Existem várias soluções para o problema que apresentas, mas para apurar qual a adequada para o teu caso será necessário saber como tens a estrutura da página. Como já referido, podes criar um [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) com o HTML necessário para replicar o problema ou colocar o mesmo na tua pergunta.

Comment: @CaioGomes por acaso sua página tem tamanho igual ao tamanho da altura da janela atual? Poderia dizer se está aplicado algum tamanho fixo a sua página?

Comment: Nada contra **também** usar o JSFiddle, mas lembre de botar o código relevante na pergunta.

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como fazer o container alcançar o rodapé? (mesmo com pouco conteúdo)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5189/como-fazer-o-container-alcancar-o-rodape-mesmo-com-pouco-conteudo)

Comment: Possível duplicata de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5189/como-fazer-o-container-alcancar-o-rodape-mesmo-com-pouco-conteudo/5193 . Não são exatamente a mesma pergunta, mas são a mesma resposta. A outra pergunta só é mais elaborada que esta

Comment: Lembre-se de escolher a melhor resposta. Você faz diversas perguntas e quem responde gosta de ter um feedback também. Abraço.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="geral">
<div id="topo">TOPO</div>
<div id="conteudo">CONTEÚDO</div>
</div>
<div id="rodape">Rodapé</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body, #geral { height: 100%; }
body > #geral { height: auto; min-height: 100%; }
#conteudo { padding-bottom: 40px; } /* O padding, deve ser o mesmo valor da altura do rodapé */
#rodape {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -40px; /* Este margin, tem que ser o mesmo valor da altura do rodapé, só     que negativo */
    height: 40px; /* E aqui, fica a altura do rodapé */
    clear: both
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi você de deixar o rodapé fixo:

assim:

```
        div#footer {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #ccc;
            color: white;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 10;
        }
```

segue exemplo:[aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/hNPnz/)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você quer algo mais ou menos assim:

Caso a página tenha pouco conteúdo, o rodapé permaneça grudado no rodapé do navegador. Clique no [Exemplo](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/rodape/rodape-fixo-no-fim-da-pagina-7.html).

Caso a página tenha bastante conteúdo, o rodapé se ajuste a altura do conteúdo que ultrapassou a altura da janela do navegador. Clique no [Exemplo](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/rodape/rodape-fixo-no-fim-da-pagina-6.html).

Veja outro exemplo usando a mesma técnica: Clique no [Exemplo](http://qrayg.com/experiment/footerstick/). (Altere o tamanho da janela para perceber o rodapé).

Outra possibilidade é que você queira o rodapé fixo. Basta usar o exemplo acima alterando a propriedade **position** do rodapé para **fixed**.

Para mais detalhes sobre essa técnica:

- [Maujor](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/rodape-embaixo-da-janela.php)
- [The Man In Blue](http://www.themaninblue.com/writing/perspective/2005/08/29/)
- [SolarDream Studios](http://qrayg.com/learn/code/footerstick/)