# Colocar Iframe com 100% de altura

Tags: html, css, iframe

Como posso fazer para um iframe ocupar 100% do seu tamanho na tela? Principalmente a questão da altura..

Tentei `style='height:100%'` mas não pega.

Preciso coloca-lo e tentar no máximo do possivel fazer que o iframe parece fazer parte da janela, umas das maneiras é removendo o SCROLL, mas para isso, eu preciso que na ALTURA ele cumpra com 100% do tamanho do documento do Iframe.

A questão anexada não me ajudou a resolver meu problema.

Desafio: deixar o iframe 100% aberto automaticamente deste código no JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/0jdo7fjL/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu dei uma olhada, mas acho que não é duplicata. Bom, pelo menos o caso é diferente, e a resposta da pergunta não me ajudou, ou talvez eu não soube interpreta-la.. Enfim, eu lançei um desafio ali :)

Comment: Esse exemplo que você deixou no jsfiddle não condiz com minha solução, faltou adicionar o html,body{height: 100%;} , preste atenção em minha resposta que vai resolver seu problema.

Comment: Pode Fazer assim:

<iframe width="500" src="https://noticias.uol.com.br/"/>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apesar de já estar respondido aqui [Div com height 100%](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6258/div-com-height-100), vou tentar clarear e explicar o comportamento, o `DOCTYPE` para HTML5 assim como o para HTML4 com Strict funciona de maneira, assim como no *Quirks mode* (Internet Explorer 10), basicamente o elemento `root` (geralmente) o `html` recebe o scrollbar, no entanto isto varia no Gecko, o qual o scrollbar seria como no `body`, de toda forma ao usar o `DOCTYPE` para HTML5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Observe o resultado:

> Fiz os exemplos no Opera, mas ele é o mesmo motor do Google Chrome, então o comportamento é idêntico
>
> [image: resultado]

Mesmo o scrollbar estando presente o "box" do elemento fica com o `height` equivalente ao conteúdo, então mesmo que aplique `height: 100%` em teu iframe isto não irá funcionar:

> [image: iframe]

Então se aplicar o height 100% nos elementos `<html>` e `<body>` o iframe vai conseguir ficar em 100%, no entanto se o elemento estiver dentro de um DIV que estiver dentro de do BODY, você precisará aplicar `height:100%;` para o DIV também, porque o 100% no `html, body` só afeta os filhos do `BODY`, mas não os "netos", também é necessário aplicar `width: 100%;` nos elementos se você precisar usar width no iframe com porcentagem, ao invés de pixels, deverá ficar assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, .main, .main iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <iframe src="https://pt.stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

No entanto você pode notar que ficaram algumas margens no iframe e também notará que foram gerados scrollbars do body:

> [image: iframe]

Então você tem que remover as margens:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body, .main, .main iframe {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.main iframe {
    border: none; /* remove as bordas do iframes*/
}
```

No entanto dependendo do navegador (motor de renderização) pode ser que gere o scrollbar na vertical do BODY, você tem duas coisas que pode fazer, ou ajustar o `box-sizing: content-box;` (ainda sim pode variar), ainda sim o que provavelmente vai ser mais eficiente é remover o scrollbar, assim você só usará o scrollbar do HTML e do BODY assim só irá usar o scrollbar de dentro do iframe:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
html, body, .main, .main iframe {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.main iframe {
    border: none; /* remove as bordas do iframes*/
}
```

### Alternativa

Existe uma alternativa simples que não irá depender de aplicar `height:100%;` em cascata, basta usar `position` (`fixed` ou `absolute`), note que scrollbar gerado é de dentro do IFRAME, o `position: fixed` não afeta o conteudo e por isto não gera o scrollbar, diferente do `position: absolute;`:

```css
.main iframe {
    border: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <iframe src="https://pt.stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

### HTML vs PHP

Anderson notei teu comentário:

> Será que só funciona em documento HTML, PHP não? O que será que impede de abrir 100%?

Não PHP não tem nada haver com client-side, o PHP **não** executa ao **mesmo tempo que o HTML**, PHP roda no *server-side* gera o HTML ou qualquer outro tipo de documento manda para o programa que trabalha o HTTP (Apache, IIS, Nginx, LightTTPD, etc) e este por sua vez envia como resposta pela internet geralmente e é recebido o HTML já processado, recomendo que leia estas postagens que fiz sobre o assunto:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177050/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168915/3635

Comment: Parabéns, ótima explicação. Já deixei o meu +1

Comment: @MateusVeloso muitíssimo obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa adicionar no css do html,body 100% na altura para que outros elementos consigam fazer isso.

```css
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://pt.stackoverflow.com" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: Não funcionou amigo..

Comment: Pode postar seu código ?

Comment: O código é grande, basicamente é um iframe de um site, dentro do meu site, e eu gostaria que o site fica-se inteiro, e não precisa-se ficar com scroll para baixo, ou para cima para ficar vendo os elementos.. Vou tentar replicar no JSFIDDLE. Seu código não funcionou amigo, o iframe da stackoverflow não ficou na altura 100%, ficou cortado e nem da para rolar(por causa do scroll bloqueado), erro similar que acontece aqui..

Comment: Lancei o desafio ali no Post, da uma lida que já atualizei Mateus.. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Só pra corrigir sua resposta, o código que enviei o iframe do stack fica 100% sim, ele só tem aquele espaço para crescer... é 100%

Comment: Bom, ta ai sua resposta amigo : https://jsfiddle.net/8Lntbs35/ seu desafio está cumprido, iframe com 100% da pagina, so tratar o scroll agora.