# html e body com altura de 100%

Tags: css3, flexbox

Galera, bom dia!

Estou usando flexbox, e vi que, para centralizar alguma div na tela, div no caso criada dentro da body, para alinhar com o align-items e justify-content (Usando os dois com o valor center, vai centralizar horizontal e vertical) só funciona se eu deixar as tags html e body com height de 100%.

Por padrão, essas tags tem quanto de altura? Porque de largura tem 100% parece.

```css
.flex-box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.form-group{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Site Lucas de Carvalho Alves</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid flex-box">
 <div class="title-panel">
  <h1>Bem vindo!</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="box-dados">
  <form class="form-box-dados" method="POST" action="" name="teste">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Endereço de e-mail</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="senha">Senha</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" placeholder="Password" name="senha">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success button-box-dados">Entrar</button>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../_cdn/jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

No codigo acima, podem verificar que ele só centraliza horizontal, vertical não, porque a html e body estão com height padrão, a unica solução é colocando a html e height 100%? Ou tem alguma outra solução?

Comment: Cara por padrão o html parece ter 100% do viewport, se vc colocar um bg-color no html vc vai ver. Já o body parece ter a altura do elemento que está dentro dele, e a largura de 100%, se vc colocar um bg-color no body não aparece nada, mas se vc colocar uma div com 100px de altura dentro do body ai vc vai ver a cor do background dele. Acho que se o pai não tiver altura vc não consegue alinhar o filho pq não há referencia pro flex funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim a solução **pode ser** colocar `height: 100%;` em `html, body`, pois isso não é um condição do flex e sim do DOCTYPE do HTML5, antigamente no [**HTML4**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/) o [**DOCTYPE Transitional**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/loose.dtd) não precisava, assumia o height por padrão como ocupando o viewport ou o conteúdo, mas o [DOCTYPE Strict](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/strict.dtd) (também html4) necessitava o `height: 100%;` e isto foi levado para HTML5 (que só possui um DOCTYPE).

Nesta resposta eu explico mais detalhadamente o comportamento do DOCTYPE:

- [**Colocar Iframe com 100% de altura**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210849/3635)

Creio que deve aplicar ao .container-fluid também, assim:

```css
 html, body, .container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
 }

.flex-box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.form-group{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid flex-box">
    <div class="title-panel">
        <h1>Bem vindo!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="box-dados">
        <form class="form-box-dados" method="POST" action="" name="teste">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Endereço de e-mail</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="senha">Senha</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" placeholder="Password" name="senha">
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-success button-box-dados">Entrar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```